# Integrating Svelte into Phoenix 1.6+ esbuild based workflow

Tags: phoenix-framework, svelte, elixir-mix, esbuild

There are a few pieces of information/code about compiling Svelte files with `esbuild`

- https://github.com/EMH333/esbuild-svelte
- https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#svelte-plugin

for example. How does one correctly integrate those (or whatever else works well for this) into  Phoenix 1.6+ `mix` environment?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://elixirforum.com/t/anyone-successfully-integrated-svelte-into-phoenix-1-6-x-esbuild/44151) article, you can use [Svonix](https://github.com/nikokozak/svonix) for that.